# How to do text classification with label probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mahout, text-mining

I'm trying to solve a text classification problem for academic purpose. I need to classify the tweets into labels like "cloud" ,"cold", "dry", "hot", "humid", "hurricane", "ice", "rain", "snow", "storms", "wind" and "other". Each tweet in training data has probabilities against all the label.  Say the message "Can already tell it's going to be a tough scoring day. It's as windy right now as it was yesterday afternoon." has 21% chance for being hot and 79% chance for wind. I have worked on the classification problems which predicts whether its wind or hot or others. But in this problem, each training data has probabilities against all the labels. I have previously used mahout naive bayes classifier which take a specific label for a given text to build model. How to convert these input probabilities for various labels as input to any classifier?

Comment: So I understand: your data comprises of tweets and a vector of probabilities indicating the likelihood of each tweet belonging to a number of labels ('hot', 'cold' etc.) and your intention is to predict those probabilities for unseen tweets?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your response. You are exactly right. I need to predict the probabilities for new tweets.

Comment: Ok, cool. How are you evaluating the performance of the predictor?

Comment: Hi Mike. Minimal deviations can be accepted(Say 1% or 2%). For example, 10% chance for being hot in test data, it should be fine if the model predicts 9% or 11% chance for being hot. Will be writing custom code to to this. There is no restriction in terms of performance. I would like to make it work with minimal deviations in the prediction result.

Comment: Don't evaluate like this---use the KL divergence between the predicted distribution and the correct one. In learning theory this is known as cross-entropy loss. It has the properties that you desire (being close won't penalise you much), but it's smooth and can be targeted for optimisation when you get around to that

Answer (score 3):

In a probabilistic setting, these probabilities reflect uncertainty about the class label of your training instance. This affects parameter learning in your classifier.

There's a natural way to incorporate this: in Naive Bayes, for instance, when estimating parameters in your models, instead of each word getting a count of one for the class to which the document belongs, it gets a count of *probability*. Thus documents with high probability of belonging to a class contribute more to that class's parameters. The situation is exactly equivalent to when learning a mixture of multinomials model using EM, where the probabilities you have are identical to the membership/indicator variables for your instances.

Alternatively, if your classifier were a neural net with softmax output, instead of the target output being a vector with a single [1] and lots of zeros, the target output becomes the probability vector you're supplied with.

I don't, unfortunately, know of any standard implementations that would allow you to incorporate these ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an off the shelf solution, you could use a learner the supports multiclass classification and instance weights.  Let's say you have `k` classes with probabilities `p_1, ..., p_k`.  For each input instance, create `k` new training instances with identical features, and with label `1, ..., k`, and assign weights `p_1, ..., p_k` respectively.

[Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial) is one such learner that supports multiclass classification with instance weights.