# Is it possible to learn a classifier from class probabilities (in sklearn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have (multiclass) training data in which the classes were learnt by aggregating hand labeled data, so some rows will have values like [0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6]. Is there anyway to use that directly as training data for a classifier. I'd rather not resort to learning 5 regression models, or just setting that data to [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]. Both seem like they'd do worse than learning directly. I know this should be possible for logistic regression at least, but no api seems to support it. (Also I'd prefer to use a better classifier than that.)

Comment: See my answer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221289/how-to-do-text-classification-with-label-probabilities/19224727#19224727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a model dependent problem. In particular - if you want to use SVM for such task you will need K SVMa, where K=number of labels (beacause SVM is a binary model, not because you want to use probabilities). Once you do it you can use "sample weighting" in order to include this kind of knowledge you are talkin about. So for SVM the answer is **yes**, it is possible and quite easy to do. In particular scikit-learn implements per-samples weighting.

It can be also incorporated in the Naive Bayes in the natural way.

In different models it may be more complex, as for example you could train a neuraln network with expected output [0,0,0,0.4,0.6] instead of binary vector, but this may cause overfitting (as this does not mean "class 4 is sure for 40%" but rather "try to model this the way, that exploits that for this sample you answer exactly [0,0,0,0.4,0.6]", so if there is a similar sample which has [0,0,0,1,1] it will try to differentiate between them. The same applies to any multi-regression approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no estimator that supports this. It is really model dependent if this is possible at all. For example for a random forest or decision tree, this would not be much different from learning a regression model (not sure what a really good splitting criterion would be, though).

I don't think that we will have an api for that in sklearn any time soon. You could modify the random forests, nearest neighbors or the neural network (upcoming) to handle this setting, though.

With a bit of work, you could probably also change the SGDClassifier, but you said you don't want a linear model. What do you regard as a "better" classifier?